# How to test nodelist with Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, jsdom

I try to test with Jest a javascript function that check if a variable is a nodelist.
It's a browser function and that will be used in browser.
here is the function :

```
/**
 * @description Check if input is a nodelist and return true or false.
 * @export
 * @param {*} input
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
export function $isNodeList(input) {
    return NodeList.prototype.isPrototypeOf(input);
}
```

The function work well in browser but if I try to test it with jest, I get the following error : *ReferenceError: NodeList is not defined*

The test file is :

```
const esmImport = require("esm")(module);
const mod = esmImport("../tools/is_nodelist.js");

const html = '<!DOCTYPE html>\
                <html>\
                    <body>\
                        <div>Hello world</div>\
                        <div>Hello</div>\
                        <div>...</div>\
                    </body>\
                </html>';

const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const { document } = (new JSDOM(html)).window;

global.document = document;

test("expect nodeList to be nodelist", () => {
    let nodeList = global.document.querySelectorAll("div");
    expect(mod.$isNodeList(nodeList)).toBe(true);
});

test("expect htmlCollection not to be nodelist", () => {
    let htmlCollection = global.document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    expect(mod.$isNodeList(htmlCollection)).toBe(false);
});
```

What is wrong in my test and how correctly test that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up the [testenvironment](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string) configuration of `jest.config.js` file. So that you don't need to use `jsdom` explicitly in your test file.

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
export function $isNodeList(input) {
  return NodeList.prototype.isPrototypeOf(input);
}
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
import * as mod from '.';

describe('59947808', () => {
  test('expect nodeList to be nodelist', () => {
    let nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('div');
    console.log('nodeList: ', nodeList);
    expect(mod.$isNodeList(nodeList)).toBe(true);
  });

  test('expect htmlCollection not to be nodelist', () => {
    let htmlCollection = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    console.log('htmlCollection: ', htmlCollection);
    expect(mod.$isNodeList(htmlCollection)).toBe(false);
  });
});
```

Unit test results:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59947808/index.test.js (8.528s)
  59947808
    ✓ expect nodeList to be nodelist (11ms)
    ✓ expect htmlCollection not to be nodelist (1ms)

  console.log src/stackoverflow/59947808/index.test.js:6
    nodeList:  NodeList {}

  console.log src/stackoverflow/59947808/index.test.js:12
    htmlCollection:  HTMLCollection {}

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.773s
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
};
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59947808